# Display object only in certain animation

Tags: animation, actions

I got two object "Rabbit" and "Knife" with armature.
I need to show Knife armature in "Cook" animation only, and hide in other animation.

Animation:
1. Cook(knife displayed) 
[image]

2. Walk(Need to hide knife)
   [image]

[image: My Outliner Structure]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Dirty way, but help me sometimes. In pose mode scale to zero bone that controls Knife

Comment: @SergeL Thanks to your suggestion, I tried your method, but the knife will scale to zero in both Cook and Walk animation.

Comment: It seems you have keyframed scale only in one animation. But you should keyframe scale with value of 1 in Cook action and with value 0 in Walk.

Answer (score 1):

**In pose mode scale to zero bone that controls object**

Just insert keyframe for scale with zero value.

**But** if you perform switching between actions, bones will inherit values from previous action (true only for non-animated values). To override zero values, you have to insert keyframe with value 1 in all actions, where object is present.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I modified a little bit about my project structure, and added two key frame into these two animation, and it worked!!! in different way LOL. 
My knife refuses to scale to zero then be disappeared.
https://imgur.com/a/ywtrUWp

But I got your point and it's really helpful, thanks.